# EXCEL: Switch to absolute reference via Find&Replace

Tags: excel, replace, wildcard

the cells in *`'Sheet1!'A1:D4`* contain relative references to another range of the same size, e.g. *`=Sheet1!'D7`*.
I'd like to copy Range *`A1:D4`* a couple of times, hence I need to replace relative references with absolute references to retain the correct reference to the source range.

Selecting each cell and pressing *F4* is not an option. Neither is using VBA or workbook functions. I'm looking explicitly for a solution via **Find&Replace**.
Fixing only columns would be easy via replacing *`"!"`* with *`"!$"`*. If it was only *`column A`*, I could replace with *`"!$A$"`*. 
I also tried incorporating brackets *( ), [ ]* or *^&* but this does not help.

I'm aware that replacing *"="* with *"#"*, copying the range and than replacing back is a workaround but don't consider it a solution.

Any new ideas are pretty welcome.
Best

I'm using EXCEL 2016

Comment: Just curious, why all the restraints? You can also, I believe, use REGEX in Find/Replace if that may help.

Comment: Hi Bruce. I have restrictions regardings VBA and WB functions, since I already know how to do it that way. Bu I'm looking for a simple solution that to share with colleagues who are less advanced EXCEL users. I agree REGEX is what I'm looking for. Finding "!?" will work. But I don't know how to construct the Replace part to retain what is found for _"?"_. Approaches from WORD did not work so far.